# Convert specific domain knowledge text to a knowledge graph

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, graphs, graph-neural-network, knowledge-graph

As part of this semester assignment , I'm working on a project that aims to to represent the knowledge in "PMBOK 6th edition, section 11: Project Risk Management (page 395 -> 458)"  and the knowledge in "PMI standard for Risk Management " (128 pages) as a knowledge graph. The generated knowledge graph will be used later to build recommendation system to infer real-time personalized recommendations.
I have been reading on how to convert unstructured text into a knowledge graph  in research papers and  articles and I have found mainly 3 ways to do this:
1/ Using a joint of  Named-entity recognition (NER) and Relation Extraction (RE) to extract the entities and the relations from your unstructured text.   
2/ taking advantage of the linguistic knowledge of Transformer models and fine tune a transformer model (BERT, T5)  for the task of extracting entities and relations. I could find some pretrained models like REBEL :https://github.com/Babelscape/rebel.
3/ use prompt engineering  (LLM (GPT)) to generate the knowledge graph.

I could not find any of the three approaches as good as I wanted:
1/ The majority of the resources I have found that tackles the first approach (NER & RE)  showcase simple tasks where the named entities and  relations are very straightforward. Example this article here: https://freedium.cfd/https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/building-a-knowledge-graph-for-job-search-using-bert-transformer-8677c8b3a2e7  where the entities are [skills, Diploma, Major, Year of experience] and the relations [DEGREE_IN, EXPERIENCE_IN..]. In this case, training  NER and RE models will be easy. But in my case, determining entities and relations is very complex. Annotating the corpus manually is incredibly tedious and labor-intensive (Could not even determine what are the entities and the relations) . You can grab a feeling of how complex it is by looking at how big our dataset is (191 pages of knowledge) and how complex the knowledge is in the corpus (many definitions, a lot of terminology...)
2/ I have used the pretrained REBEL model but  the results looked weird. (redundant relations, sometimes the extracted relations make non sense). And So I wanted to fine tune BERT for this specific task on my custom data (PMBOK, PMI) but I really could not understand how to do this   (what should be the data format to train and test the transformer model?, how to evaluate the model ?...)
3/ The fact that LLM are stochastic models,  a lot of variations in the generated graphs for each prompt (sometimes huge differences)  and this lead to huge ambiguity because I cannot evaluate how good the graph is in representing the knowledge.
I'm open to any  other resources and any other inspirations or approaches to tackle this project. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to start with evaluating the goodness of a given knowledge graph. Solving this will help you later. I am also interested in evaluating the goodness of knowledge graphs. Maybe you need to get some annotations just for ecaluation.

Comment: @Ggjj11 Absolutely, I think I need to to extract the most important general concepts in this specific domain before feeding it into the machine .And then maybe I can evaluate how good is a generated graph. Thank you for your response.

Comment: It somehow reminds me about evaluating cluster methods. Clusters can be represented by neighborhood graphs, i.e. a adjacency matrix (or a Laplace matrix). Based on this you can compute e.g. the rand index (or any other confusion based metric) when comparing two adjacency matrices ...

Comment: @Ggjj11 very interesting, Maybe I can use this to merge similar relations (parts of the graph). Thank you for your comment.